# response times on Jmeter HTTP POST request

Tags: post, jmeter

I have one HTTP POST request where I have to send some parameters for search filter. I did this fine, but I want to measure response time (how long does it take to receive all data that is searched).

What "Sample times" in View results in table are showing? Is it sample time for sending POST request or for receiving searched data?

Any advises how to do this properly?

Answer (score 0):

Elapsed time:

> JMeter measures the elapsed time from just before sending the request to just after the last response has been received. JMeter does not include the time needed to render the response, nor does JMeter process any client code, for example Javascript.

See:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html

Comment: So when I send post request I will receive some response (I see this in response tab under results tree) and sample time is calculated on this response. But what this response actually is? Is it some confirmation that my post request is properly sent or this is response with searched data? Response rendering is not important to me but searched data is. Is there a way to receive this data and to measure sample time for is?